# How to make timer not freeze program

Tags: vb.net, timer

When I start the timer during a process it freezes my program. Is there any way to resolve it? To make it not freeze all buttons in the GUI while the timer is working?

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
   Do somting...(I sending mail throught SMTP)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

This has nothing to do with the timer.

You're running a long (network-bound) operation on the UI thread.
Whenever code is running on the UI thread, the UI cannot respond.

You need to run that operation asynchronously or on a background thread.

Comment: Just to add to SLaks answer, if you're using .NET 4.5 you can leverage the async command (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)
If you're using a lower version you will need to create a new BackgroundWorker

Comment: @Mataniko: That's not quite true; you can use `SendAsync()` (EAP) in earlier versions too.

Comment: True, I missed the actual content of his Timer vs the actual question: Making a timer not freeze.

Answer (score 1):

Incase you still don't understand Slacks answer ...

1. instantiate the thread

   ```
    Public t1 As Threading.Thread
   ```
2. make a call from your timer to the thread.

   ```
   Private Sub someTimer(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles someTimer.Tick
   t1 = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf SomeSubRoutine))
   t1.Start()
   end sub
   ```
3. Run email code in the subroutine

   ```
   sub Subroutine()

   email code here // make sure that therer are no GUI or Main Thread calls else you have to get into delegates and invoke methods

   end sub
   ```
4. your done, won't hang up the Gui Thread, however i do recoment staying away from timers I would call the thread directly

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use Application.DoEvents() inside your loop in Timer1_Tick function if you have a for-loop or while-loop inside the function.

Comment: This can still pause stuff for annoyingly long periods, though, if much time is spent...say...waiting to connect to the mail server.